# entity framework static cache

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching, static-methods

I'm working on monitoring application. For example, printers, recorded in the users profile. The objective is to get a list of users of each printers. An admin may have to filter results.. by user, by pc, default printers... and export the result in CSV. So when an admin do an export, the csv needs to be related to active filter. I've tried to create a static cache with EF 6, to keep theses filters.

Cache class

```
public class PrintersCache
{
    public static AuditprinterDBEntities1 db = new AuditprinterDBEntities1();
    public static IQueryable<AuditPrinter> auditPrinterCache = null;
    public static IQueryable<AuditPrinter> AuditPrinterCache
    {
        get
        {
            if (auditPrinterCache == null) auditPrinterCache = db.AuditPrinter.Include(a => a.Pc).Include(a => a.PrintersConfig).Include(a => a.Users);
            return auditPrinterCache;
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller, I'm calling my class

```
static IQueryable<AuditPrinter> auditPrinter = PrintersCache.AuditPrinterCache;
```

And then, in the beginin of filter method :

```
auditPrinter = PrintersCache.AuditPrinterCache;
```

And the export method :

```
public void ExportCSV()
{
    var sw = new StringWriter();
    sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3}", "PcName", "Date", "ActivityName", "UserName"));

    foreach (var record in auditPrinter)        
    {
        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3}", record.Pc.PcName, record.Date, record.Activity.ActivityName, record.Users.UserName));
    }
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Export.csv");
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.Write(sw);
    Response.End();
}
```

It's working... but searching is little slow, and for example, If I click on my search button 5 or 6 times very quickly I get an  `'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException'` . `The underlying provider failed on Open.` Do I need a second level cache ?

EDIT : Seach filter method

```
public ActionResult LaunchSearch(string keyword, string keyword2, int chx, int pid, int fid)
    {
        auditPrinter = PrintersCache.AuditPrinterCache;
        string returnpartial = "";
        switch (chx)
        {
            case 1:
                if(pid!=0)
                {
                    auditPrinter = auditPrinter.Where(a => a.Printers.PrinterId == pid);
                }
                returnpartial = "Indexprinter";
                break;
            case 2:
                if (pid != 0)
                {
                    auditPrinter = auditPrinter.Where(a => a.UserId == pid);
                } else
                {
                    auditPrinter = auditPrinter.OrderBy(a => a.Users.UserName).ThenBy(a => a.Pc.PcName);
                }
                returnpartial = "Indexvuser";
                break;
            case 3:
                if (pid != 0)
                {
                    auditPrinter = auditPrinter.Where(a => a.Pc.PcId == pid);
                }
                else
                {
                    auditPrinter = auditPrinter.OrderBy(a => a.Pc.PcName).ThenBy(a => a.Users.UserName);
                }
                returnpartial = "Indexvpc";
                break;
        }

        if (keyword != "")
        {
            switch (chx)
            {
                case 1:
                    auditPrinter = auditPrinter.Where(a => a.Users.UserName.Contains(keyword)).OrderBy(a => a.Users.UserName).ThenBy(a => a.Pc.PcName);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    auditPrinter = auditPrinter.Where(a => a.Users.UserName.Contains(keyword)).OrderBy(a => a.Users.UserName).ThenBy(a => a.Pc.PcName);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    auditPrinter = auditPrinter.Where(a => a.Pc.PcName.Contains(keyword)).OrderBy(a => a.Pc.PcName).ThenBy(a => a.Users.UserName);
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (keyword2 != "")
        {
            switch (chx)
            {
                case 1:
                    auditPrinter = auditPrinter.Where(a => a.Users.UserName.Contains(keyword) && a.Pc.PcName.Contains(keyword2)).OrderBy(a => a.Pc.PcName).ThenBy(a => a.Users.UserName);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    auditPrinter = auditPrinter.Where(a => a.Users.UserName.Contains(keyword) && a.Pc.PcName.Contains(keyword2)).OrderBy(a => a.Pc.PcName).ThenBy(a => a.Users.UserName);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    auditPrinter = auditPrinter.Where(a => a.Pc.PcName.Contains(keyword) && a.Users.UserName.Contains(keyword2)).OrderBy(a => a.Users.UserName).ThenBy(a => a.Pc.PcName);
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (fid != 0)
        {
            switch (fid)
            {
                case 1:
                    auditPrinter = auditPrinter.Where(a => a.PrintersConfig.IsDefault == true);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    auditPrinter = auditPrinter.Where(a => a.PrintersConfig.IsDefault == false);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return PartialView(returnpartial, auditPrinter.ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An entity framework context should not be static**, it's lifetime should be as short as possible.

Remove your cache class and put the context creation and query inside your `LaunchSearch` method and do not forget to dispose this context.

Think about caching only if there is a true performance issue, caching complex objects (like entities) is rarely a good idea. If you need cache, try with HTTP cache, client or server side.

---

```
public ActionResult LaunchSearch(string keyword, string keyword2, int chx, int pid, int fid)
{
    using(var db = new AuditprinterDBEntities1())
    {
        var auditPrinter = db.AuditPrinter.Include(a => a.Pc).Include(a => a.PrintersConfig).Include(a => a.Users);

        // Do whatever you need to do and return result ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I understand. For export in csv, what's is the best cache technique ?

Comment: Why do you think you need to cache it ?

Comment: Because, in my csv export method, I need to export list based on view active filters. That's why I Thought it was the only solution, to use the result of a query in another method. Perhaps it is a bad idea, and there is a more simple solution...

Comment: Query the database with the correct filter each time you need data, it's really meant to be used that way. A database engine already provides transparent caching but also provides more efficient ways to search/filter data. Now *if* you really have a performance issue, cache is an option but not always the right solution.

Comment: But in this situation, I'm wondering how I could get the current value of auditPrinter in the export CSV method without cache. That's the point that I don't understand.

Comment: You don't need cache, get a fresh IQueryable on a fresh context instance. You can inline it in your method. I added a sample code to my answer. One action = one instance of context, do not share it and avoid multiple instances of the same context per action.

Comment: Static cache was not a good idea... and I took another way, thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change the PrinterCache as follows.

```
public class PrintersCache
{
    public static AuditprinterDBEntities1 db = new AuditprinterDBEntities1();
    static PrintersCache()
    {
        AuditPrinterCache = db.AuditPrinter
                            .Include(a => a.Pc)
                            .Include(a => a.PrintersConfig)
                            .Include(a => a.Users);
    }
    public static IQueryable<AuditPrinter> AuditPrinterCache
    {
        get; private set;
    }
}
```

This still doesnt solve the problem, because you are actually not caching. Just storing a linq query, this will get called lazyly when you loop through `foreach (var record in auditPrinter)`.

So this will be called multiple times and result in performance issue, to avoid it store the results by making it to list. So the class should look like

```
public class PrintersCache
{
    public static AuditprinterDBEntities1 db = new AuditprinterDBEntities1();
    static PrintersCache()
    {
        AuditPrinterCache = db.AuditPrinter
                            .Include(a => a.Pc)
                            .Include(a => a.PrintersConfig)
                            .Include(a => a.Users).ToList;
    }
    public static List<AuditPrinter> AuditPrinterCache
    {
        get; private set;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use IQueryable, because in my filter method I do query like that : auditPrinter = auditPrinter.Where(a => a.PrintersConfig.IsDefault == true); . For the error inner exception says 'The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting'

Comment: @mrplume , there is no problem to query the cache using a Where condition. With this implementation, all the information about the AuditPrinter are retrieved once. You can use a the [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx)  class of the .Net framework to automatically renew the cache for a certain duration.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Memory cache, you can do thing like that:

```
class PrintersCache
{
    private const string CacheName = "MyCacheName";        
    private const string AuditPrinterKey = "AuditPrinterKey";
    private static readonly MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache(CacheName);
    private const int CacheExpirationInMinutes = 20;

    public static List<AuditPrinter> GetAuditPrinterCache()
    {
        // Create a lazy object to retrieve the data when the cache has expired
        var newLazyValue = new Lazy<List<AuditPrinter>>(() =>
        {
            // You should not keep an instance of your db context without disposing it. Also The instantiation of a db context is cheap.
            using (var db = new AuditprinterDBEntities1())
            {
                return db.AuditPrinter
                    .Include(a => a.Pc)
                    .Include(a => a.PrintersConfig)
                    .Include(a => a.Users).ToList();
            }
        });

        // Return the instance of the Lazy object. If the cahce has expired a new instance of the Lazy object is created.
        return
            ((Lazy<List<AuditPrinter>>)
                memoryCache.AddOrGetExisting(AuditPrinterKey, newLazyValue, new CacheItemPolicy()
                {
                    // Defines that the cache will expired after 20min
                    AbsoluteExpiration = new DateTimeOffset(
                        DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(CacheExpirationInMinutes))
                })).Value;
    }
}
```

- Using the `AddOrGetExisting` Method of the memory cache, you will provide some kind of fallback if the object does not exist in the cache.
- Using a `Lazy<T>`, you will only call the database when the cache is empty.
- using a AbsoluteExpiration, you can ensure that your cache will be updated (every 20 minutes in this case) if there are some changes in the database.

Because `List<T>` is queryable, you can retrieve you data like that :

```
// Initializes your query
var query = PrintersCache.GetAuditPrinterCache().Where(a => a.Printers.PrinterId == pid);

// apply your others conditions here
...
query = query .Where(a => a.Users.UserName.Contains(keyword)).OrderBy(a => a.Users.UserName).ThenBy(a => a.Pc.PcName);

// Return your new filtered list
return query.ToList()
```